# Adding Navigation Menu in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to add a navigation menu to the top of my page through Drupal.

I've gone through numerous walkthroughs of creating menus, enabling the menus, setting the menus to appear on specific views, and yet, I ahve no menu.

I have not yet found a wlkthrough or any post that shows me step-by-step how to add the menu to a page, and I am beyond frustrated to think that this feature would go without full documentation.

If anyone can provide me with any help on how to add a menu to a Drupal 7 page, please let me know.

I've already looked over these links:

https://www.drupal.org/node/37375

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/path

https://www.drupal.org/node/1225606

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu

https://www.drupal.org/node/788972

https://www.drupal.org/node/1578582

https://www.drupal.org/node/286376

http://www.success.grownupgeek.com/index.php/2010/07/25/how-add-tab-views/

PLEASE HELP ME!

This is a link to the template I am using:

http://visia.envato.tabvn.com/

I would like to set the menu-navigation bar as it shows in the top of the template.

Comment: Well, the fix was silly, yet important. Under `Structure → Blocks` you should find a block called `Main Navigation`. There is a button to the left of the block that says `Configure Block`. Underneath "Configure Block," underneath `Visibility Settings` there is a `tab labelled Content Types`. My issue was that all of these content types were selected, excluding all content types. I had to un-select them all. You must `only select the content types you wish to EXCLUDE the menu from!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used that theme, but there are a couple different ways to enable the menu.

**1. Enable the block**

Each menu has a corresponding block, so go to structure -> blocks -> find your menu and move it to the corresponding region.

**2. Add the theme feature in your theme and place the corresponding php in your page.tpl.php file.**
Open your theme's .info file and make sure you see " features[] = main_menu " (and make sure it's not commented out.

Then, in your page.tpl.php file, put this where you want your nav::

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
        <nav>
            <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Main menu'))); ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This does appear to work, yet I was hoping to do as much as I could without touching `php`. This was very helpful though, so thank you. I ended up finding my answer, yet it was so silly that I felt stupid writing it in as an answer. Because your answer does work (and its the only answer provided) I will accept your answer, but I will provide my actual fix as a comment on my original post.